# pycharm python packages installed but throws dependency error on import of packages (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm, pytz

I am running python 3.6 on my system and have come across an unexpected situation.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>    "C:/Users/Amrit/Documents/CodeDump/PythonFunctions/remove_punctuations.py", line 1, in
>
> import pandas as pd
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 19, in 
>      "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>
> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz']

I have checked the list of installed packages in the "Project Interpreter" section under "Settings" and it shows that both 'numpy' and 'pytz' are listed in the Package list.

I wasn't facing these issues until recently when importing the pandas package started giving dependency error. I am not sure where these packages are broken.

Comment: It is working for me, not getting any such error. Check the installed one are for the same project interpreter you are using.

Comment: @Nand the python interpreter is "Python 3.6 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"  which is the conda installation.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Turns out one of the python files in the directory "Python Functions" was named 'tokenize', so there was a naming conflict between the user-defined function and the built-in function 'tokenize'. Although, I am still confused about an error "AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core' " which was being output everytime I tried to import pandas. Any clue what's the background to this?